# SQL Where Condition fails to find data which it finds when not using subselect or variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause

I have a rather strange phenomenon.

```
DECLARE @SearchLE float
DECLARE @CompareLE float

SET @SearchLE = 
(
SELECT
    LastValue
FROM
    TableA
WHERE
    Articlenumber = 'example'
)

SELECT @SearchLE as SearchValue
```

returns 66,4
This is correct.

```
SET @CompareLE =
(
SELECT TOP 1
            LastValue
        FROM
            TableB
        WHERE
            Articlenumber = 'example'
        AND
            LastValue= 
            --@SearchLE
            66.4
)

SELECT @CompareLE as CompareValue
```

returns 66,4
This is obviously also correct.

When I uncomment `@SearchLE` and comment out 66.4, then the second `SELECT` statement returns NULL.

Can someone explain that to me? Both datatypes in the tables are float.

It is all in one SQL Server database, and I use SQL Server Management Studio, if that is important. Note that my return values are separated with a comma instead of a period.

I also tried `TRY_CONVERT` to float on both values, without success.

Comment: What happes if you manually set your `@SearchLE` value to `66.4` rather than using the first SQL statement and keep the `LastValue=@SearchLE` in your second statement?

Comment: @iamdave In this case, I am getting the expected result, Search and Compare are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float is an approximate data type, so comparing a float with a float is usually not a good idea.  Convert your values to decimal if you want to compare. If possible update the data type in the table, otherwise you have to convert it in your query, but that could cause performance issues if you have a large table.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @SearchLE decimal (8,2)

...

SET @CompareLE =
(
SELECT TOP 1
            LastValue
        FROM
            TableB
        WHERE
            Articlenumber = 'example'
        AND
            CAST( LastValue as decimal (8,2)) = @SearchLE

)
```

Comment: That did solve the problem. TIL to never compare floats again. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that conversion from float to a number is sargable -- meaning that the conversion prevents SQL Server from using an index or pruning partitions.  So I recommend direct comparisons:

```
LastValue > (@SearchLE - 0.0001) and LastValue < (@SearchLE + 0.0001)
```

This can use an index on `LastValue`.

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
ABS(LastValue - @SearchLE) < 0.0001
```

But this doesn't use an index.

If you need to do such comparisons, you probably want to change `LastValue` to be a `decimal`/`numeric` type.